# Flash Object - off the shelf or build from scratch

Tags: flash

I've only taken one flash course back in school, but now I have a client who's asking me to make a flash project that's similar to this:

http://www.harte-hanks.com/static/base/hh_mainmenu.swf

He wants to preserve all the dynamic effects, the faded-mirroring at bottom, the slide shows etc...

He wants to change the colours, add more boxes, and change the text.

So my question is, do I need to build something like this from scratch?  Or are there off the shelf solutions I can customize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i built from scratch because it was faster